# Has Ibrahim addressed Allah with feminine verb?

Tags: quran, arabic

Chapter/Surah: 26
Verse/Ayah: 87

وَلَا تُخْزِنِي يَوْمَ يُبْعَثُونَ

And corpus.quran.com says this verb is feminine.

https://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(26:87:2)

So, is this source accurate?

Comment: This is simply an error on corpus quran, because this is the 2nd perspn singular أنت (see at the bottom of [this page](https://www.almaany.com/ar/analyse/ar-ar/%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%B2%D9%89/) . And further a verb has no gender.

Answer (score 4):

### Translations of the verse

> وَلَا **تُخْزِنِي** يَوْمَ يُبْعَثُونَ

The [verse](https://legacy.quran.com/26/87) was translated as follows:

> *And do not **disgrace me** on the Day they are [all] resurrected* - <sup>(Sahih International)</sup>
> *And **disgrace me** not on the Day when (all the creatures) will be resurrected*; <sup>(Muhsin Khan)</sup>
> *And **abase me** not on the day when they are raised,* <sup>(Pickthall)</sup>
> *"And let **me** not be in **disgrace** on the Day when (men) will be raised up;-* <sup>(Yusuf Ali)</sup>
> *And **disgrace me** not on the day when they are raised* <sup>(Shakir)</sup>
> *And do not **disgrace me** the Day when they are made to rise (again),* <sup>(Dr. Ghali)</sup>

As you may see all translators agree on the fact that Ibraheem () addressed his creator exalted be HE in the 2nd person singular (You). Only Yusuf Ali used or focused on a different verb, without changing the meaning too much. This already should show that the translation and explanation made on corpus quran should be revised!

The point of discussion here is the verb conjugated in the verse as:

> تُخْزِنِي

### The statements in corpus quran

Let's first check the quotes made on corpus quran:
[image]

First let us clarify the meaning of the Arabic quote:
<sup>In the following I'll be translating from Arabic language, as these translations are of my own, take them with the necessary care.</sup>

> فعل مضارع مجزوم والياء ضمير متصل في محل نصب مفعول به

This can be translated as follows (please note I'm not familiar with the correct translation of Arabic grammatical terminology in English):

> A verb in present tense, which has a connected pronoun, which refers to (or replaces) an accusative (which would have the diacritic "fathah").

There's simply nothing pointing at feminine in this grammatical analysis of the "sentence" "disgrace me تُخْزِنِي".

In other words without connected "the reference" or "addition" "me" (first person singular pronoun) the verb would be conjugated:

> تُخْزِي

### Deeper look into Arabic grammar and conjugation

Let's go deeper and check the origins of this conjugated verb. The verb we are looking for is

> أَخْزَى or
> هو أَخْزَى

In Arabic a verb is always referred to in the third person singular in past tense we could say in Arabic: He + verb in past tense = infinitive.
In present tense the third person singular is:

> يُخْزِي

This verb means to disgrace somebody.

Which originated from:

> خَزِيَ

This verb is referring to a feeling of disgrace. As [خِزْي or الخِزْي](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%90%D8%B2%D9%92%D9%8A/) means disgrace and is related to humiliation.

Now to make it clear and lift any doubt, we need to check the conjugation tables for then present tense     المضارع  which might also be referred to as المضارع المعلوم ([see here](https://www.almaany.com/ar/analyse/ar-ar/%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%B2%D9%89/) المضارع المعلوم at the bottom of the page) of the verb and here we would find that:

> تُخْزِي

Corresponds to the 2nd person singular masculine:

> أنتَ

However the table at almaany is neither in the correct order nor does it use agreed upon terms in fact in Arabic we have three tenses: past الماضي , present المضارع and imperative الأمر any other tense represented in their tables are specific cases of past or present or imperative which only apply under certain grammatical influences and are usually not discussed as tenses in specific books.
Also note that both future tense and imperative could be derived from the present tense of a verb (the future more easily).

Therefore here's the table as most Arabic native speakers have learnt at school and  would agree upon:

[image]